# Как максимально быстро кликнуть по элементу в браузере?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, google-chrome, webbrowser, уведомления

Есть потребность реализовать расширение-кликер для хрома. У меня есть АМО CRM в ней нам падают лиды, далее, кто первый успел взять лид нажатием кнопки "принять" на всплывающем окне, тот и будет с ним работать. У моей коллеги, написан, какой-то софт/расширение, которое кликает на эту кнопку ещё до появления её в визуальной части сайта. Написал такой скрипт:

```
function observeAndClickElement() {
    const targetSelector = '.f5-notifier-notification-action_btn';

    // Функция для нажатия на элемент
    function clickElement(element) {
        if (element) {
            // Вызов функции клика
            element.click();
            console.log("Кнопка в уведомлении была нажата");
        }
    }

    // Функция для рекурсивной проверки наличия элемента
    function checkForElement() {
        const notificationButton = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
        clickElement(notificationButton);

        // Запуск следующей проверки
        requestAnimationFrame(checkForElement);
    }

    // Запуск первой проверки
    checkForElement();
}

// Запуск отслеживания и нажатия на элемент
observeAndClickElement();
```

С таким скриптом, коллега всё равно берёт все заявки, а значит каким-то образом раньше меня получает информацию, о полявлении кнопки. Дсотупа к какой-либо серверной части нет ни у меня, ни у неё.
Как можно оптимизировать/переписать код чтобы стать первым или хотябы забирать часть её заявок, если вдруг потолком будет скорость интернета и другие факторы на которые я не смогу повлиять?

Comment: мб проще инжектить свой код еще на моменте принятия события на клиенте, до отрисовки кнопки) тоесть, приходит событие с сервера (нужное событие), как только его получаем, обрываем дальнейшую обработку и отсылаем свой запрос с нужными данными по нужному адресу) не сабмит формы, а именно свой запрос, так как формы как таковой по сути и не будет вовсе... 
P.S. потом вам добавят капчу :))))

Comment: @Jour Добрый день! Может быть у вас есть статья, как мне вообще онаружить такой запрос в браузере и обратиться к нему?)

Answer (score 1):

##### Во-первых обход

Функция `document.querySelector`, конечно, довольно быстрая функция, но мы сможем делать быстрее если будем искать не с document, а с более близкого элемента. К примеру - с панели уведомлений. Один раз в начале находите панель уведомлений или что-то ещё ближе к кнопке, сохраните его в каком-нибудь константе и потом оттуда используйте `querySelector`.

```js
const panelNotifications = document.querySelector(selectors);

function click() {
  panelNotifications.querySelector(buttonSelectors)?.click();
}
```

Так мы выиграем несколько миллисекунд

##### Во-вторых слушание

Если мы сможем создать событие, которое послушает сервер или другое событие, на которое приходит уведомление то будем быстрее. Метод с `requestAnimationFrame` работает каждые 0.006-0.007 секунд, а прямой обработчик будет работать моментально.
Ну можно попробовать слушать `WebSocket` если сайт работает через него:

```js
const socket = new WebSocket(link);
socket.addEventListener(`message`, (event) => {
  click();
});
```

---

Пока что эти методы, но задача довольно интересная, я ещё подумаю.

Comment: Дополню, что все манипуляции проводятся из браузера менеджера, доступа к серверным возможностям нет. На других форумах пишут, что можно попробовать API, но я не знаю, как найти запрос, который мне нужен:( Сейчас попробую изменить код, чтобы поиск шел из ближайшего элемента. Сообщу, если поможет. Но мне кажется, что у коллеги, что-то более технологичное, чем отслеживание в структуре DOM.

Comment: @ВадимКоломеец если будет более подробный пример, попробую сказать более точную оптимизацию за счет DOM.

Comment: Могу я написать вам на почту с примерами кода и скринами по данному вопросу? Тут я ограничен в 600 символов.

Comment: Вместо `element.querySelector` так же попробуйте `document.getElementById`. Id я вно работает быстрее, но я не уверен будет ли он работать быстее selector-а с близкого элемента. Есть идея что DOM создает ключи для id в самом запуске, таким способом не нуждается в поиске элемента каждый раз.

Comment: Ну в почте буду смотреть только я, а тут могут помочь ещё люди. Вы дополните вопрос, не надо писать в комментариях.

Comment: У кнопки, какждый раз уникальный id, создается по какой-то маске, пример id="submit-btn-lead_25793bfd8897bdf"

Comment: @ВадимКоломеец, `ещё до появления её в визуальной части сайта` если действительно именно **до**, возможно слушалка сразу запрос на бэк шлет, а не клик в кнопку(минус время на генерацию кнопки и обработку клика). ну прям как @Jour описал `по какой-то маске, пример id="submit-btn-lead_...` генерацию с этой маской и поищите в коде, если конечно она такая не с бека прилетела... в любом случае стоит поискать генератор кнопки(`append, appendChild, innerHTML, createElement` и вот это всё...) главное чтобы бэк не оказался таким: отправка ей, sleep(100500), а уже после отправка остальным :3

Comment: @Jour не ну мы все же попробуем быть оптимистами и посоветуем заменить `gen(<a href='lead'>)` например на `gen(<iframe src='lead'>)` ну или `img` а там уже браузер сам потеребит бэк за ссылку :3

Comment: @Jour нуу максимально быстрый вариант — это ловить событие на стороне клиента и отправить ответ. Можно даже вручную. А как вы будете ловить это событие это уже второй вопрос.

Comment: Есть вариант, что у нее просто сниффер стоит и он еще до браузера реагирует на сетевые события.

Comment: @Jour ну вариантов ускорить много. Просто у нас нет ни полноценного примера, не особого представления что там творится. И все эти решения лишь абстракции. Вот я и предлагаю самые логичные на мой взгляд решения, которые должны работать практически в любых обстоятельствах.

Comment: @eccs0103 добрый день! Вчера нашел вебсокет с уведомлениями, думаю через него можно остлеживать запросы приходящие с сервера, НО я не знаю, как это реализовать без бесконечных запросов к серверну от клиента, может быть вы можете дать какую-то наводку на технологию, которой можно было бы ожидать нужный мне ответ сервера?

Comment: @ВадимКоломеец дополните вопрос этим кодом. Думаю смастерим что-нибудь полезное